# WSO2 SynchronizeRepositoryRequest frequency

Tags: apache-axis, wso2

We're working with WSO2 SVN synchronizer (for our WSO2-AM 1.10.0).

Looking at the log, it seems that it takes ~10 seconds from the time that an API has completed updating at the manager node (either published, deatviated, edited, or any other change) and until the manager notifies the cluster about the change (by sending the SynchronizeRepositoryRequest message as in the sample below).

```
TID: [1] [] [2017-03-09 17:26:47,101] 
0000s7.com|orgInternalId|1 INFO     {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask} -  
Sent [SynchronizeRepositoryRequest{tenantId=1, tenantDomain='0000s7.com', 
messageId=2f834c01-9c10-44da-8b3c-e84030d393be}]
```

Even though 10 seconds is not much, we prefer this time to be shorter. Is there a configurable parameter to control this? What are the impact of reducing this time?

Also we could not find the relevant code (CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask, SynchronizeRepositoryRequest, etc) in WSO2 git. We only saw old carbon.core code in an SVN repository https://svn.wso2.org. Can someone point us to the updated code (for carbon 4.4.x or 5.0.3?)

Comment: I am not aware of a such setting to reduce this time period. You can find the code here (https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.4.3/core/org.wso2.carbon.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/deployment/CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java).

Comment: Can you explain in a few words what happens at the manager node from publishing an API until the sync message is sent to the cluster? The little I know about single node, is that when API is created it is written in the DB, and once published I see files created in the synapse-config directory plus it appears in the carbon console's service bus (I guess this reflects the ESB memory?). Can you elaborate about the publishing process in a cluster environment? What comes first (service bus? synapse-config? SVN checkin?) a few words will better direct me to look at the right code.

Comment: And one more related question: if I got the deployment interval set to run every 2 seconds, why is the message sent only ~10 seconds after the API is published? What is keeping it from being sent?

Comment: In a cluster environment, once you publish an API from the publisher, it creates the synapse artifact and push that artifact to gateway manager using service calls. In gateway, API loading is hot deployable and once the file is pushed to <wso2am>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api location API will be loaded to the gateway. When there is a change, gw-manager will send a cluster message to the other nodes in the environment. Basically, other nodes are gateway worker nodes. Then they will pull the API from the SVN.

Comment: AFAIU, this 10 second time interval is used to load the API to the gateway manager node, push that API to SVN repo and to send the cluster message. In order to check more on this, we have to go through the code and see.